# Css selector: Chose attribute value doesn't work

Tags: css, python-3.x, web-scraping, css-selectors

I am struggling to choose a certain button on a webpage I want to scrape. I am using Chrome Inspection mode.

The website is this one: https://www.mrlodge.de/wohnungen/ and I want to select the "Mehr laden" button, which is German for "load more".

I have tried things like:

```
[button="Mehr laden"]

.button>"Mehr laden"
```

Here is a HTML snippet:
[image: Html snippet]

Comment: Please post actual code in a [mcve] and not a picture of code - [Why not upload pictures of code on SO when askling a question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: You can't use CSS to select an element by it's text contents. You need Javascript.

Comment: Right click => copy => copy selector

Comment: grammar and removed thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*This is assuming you are trying to select it in css:*

Post this in your css to select that button:

```
div.mrl-objectsearch__list>div.mrl-ft-results-more.mrlobject-list-more>button.button{
    //do some css f.e.:
    background: #000000 !important;
}
```

This works aswell but you could select another button with the same class name:

```
button.button {
    //do some css f.e.:
    background: #000000 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A shorter selector would seem to be

```
.mrlobject-list-more button
```